# Apache Solr fix max no. of documents per request

Tags: solr, lucene

I have configured Apache Solr 6.6.3 to provide search for few domains. It is just like a search engine somehow where some fixed no of results are shown on page that are mostly 10 documents.

The problem I am facing is that I want to apply a hard limit for upper bound of documents per request in Solr. As there is a change that user will get all documents with single request which will degrade Solr performance.
How to configure it in Solr.

Answer (score 1):

That should really be the job of your controller / middleware, since a frontend application usually shouldn't have direct access to Solr anyway. Do `min(1000, <value from request>)` before setting the `rows` parameter in Solr.

If you want to lock the `rows` parameter to a specific value (but then it can't be lower either), you can [set a specific value in the requestHandler definition](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SearchHandler):

```
<lst name="invariants">
  <int name="rows">50</int>
</lst>
```

Comment: Thanks sir but I want for upper limit, user can request lower than that limit such as in case of dictionary, only one result should be returned but for some other cases, 10 results.

Comment: Then you'll have to do it in your controller.